# Not getting the input values present inside the table using Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, html-table

I have some input fields inside the table cell but I am unable to get those values using Angular 8. My codes are given below.

```
<tr *ngFor="let opt of ConfigArr; let i = index;">
   <td class="sticky-col first-col">
      {{opt.attrName1}}({{opt.attr1}})
   </td>
   <td class="sticky-col second-col">
      {{opt.attrName2}}({{opt.attr2}})
   </td>
   <td>
      <input class="form-control" matInput placeholder="Add MRP" aria-label="MRP" [value]="opt.MRP">
   </td>
   <td>
      <input class="form-control" matInput placeholder="Add BaseUnitPrice" aria-label="BaseUnitPrice" [value]="opt.BaseUnitPrice">
   </td>
   <td>
      <input class="form-control" matInput placeholder="Add DiscountValue" aria-label="DiscountValue" [value]="opt.DiscountValue">
   </td>
   <td>
      <input class="form-control" class="form-control" matInput placeholder="MinBuyQty" aria-label="MinBuyQty" [value]="opt.MinBuyQty">
   </td>
   <td>
      <input class="form-control" matInput placeholder="Add MinimumPrice" aria-label="MinimumPrice" [value]="opt.MinimumPrice">
   </td>
   <td>
      <input class="form-control" matInput placeholder="Add TaxPercentage" aria-label="TaxPercentage" [value]="opt.TaxPercentage">
   </td>
   <td>
      <input class="form-control" matInput placeholder="Add TaxAmount" aria-label="TaxAmount" [value]="opt.TaxAmount">
   </td>
   <td>
      <input class="form-control" matInput placeholder="Add DiscountPrice" aria-label="DiscountPrice" [value]="opt.DiscountPrice">
   </td>
   <td>
      <input class="form-control" matInput placeholder="Add MaxBuyQty" aria-label="MaxBuyQty" [value]="opt.MaxBuyQty">
   </td>
   <td>
      <input class="form-control" matInput placeholder="Add MaximumPrice" aria-label="MaximumPrice" [value]="opt.MaximumPrice">
   </td>
</tr>

<button class="btn btn-md btn-primary" type="button" (click)="addImage($event, AddImages,i)">
   Add <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
```

Typescript code is given below.

```
for(let i=0; i< res['data']['Attributes'][this.ColumnNames[0]].length;i++){
   for(let j=0;j< res['data']['Attributes'][this.ColumnNames[1]].length;j++){
       let data = {
                  'attr1':res['data']['Attributes'][this.ColumnNames[0]][i],
                  'attrName1':attrName1,
                  'attr2': res['data']['Attributes'][this.ColumnNames[1]][j],
                  'attrName2': attrName2,
                  "MRP": '',
                  "BaseUnitPrice":'',
                  "DiscountValue": '',
                  "MinBuyQty":'',
                  "MinimumPrice":'',
                  "TaxPercentage":'',
                  "TaxAmount":'',
                  "DiscountPrice":'',
                  "MaxBuyQty":'',
                  "MaximumPrice":''
                }
                this.ConfigArr.push(data);
   }

addImage(event: Event, template: any, index: any) {
     console.log('all values', this.ConfigArr);
}
```

Here after typing values inside the input field when user is clicking on `Add` button then I am not getting the input field values for each row inside the console. I need after user will put the input values It should be inside `this.ConfigArr` for each row.

Comment: Can you share form code. Please share input filed code with full form

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to capture it explicitly. 
That's why angular have `ngModel`.

```
<input [(ngModel)]="opt.BaseUnitPrice" class="form-control" matInput placeholder="Add BaseUnitPrice" aria-label="BaseUnitPrice" >
```

So this will update the `ConfigArr` directly.

Comment: I am using reactive form so can not put the [(ngModel)] inside it.

Comment: Hmmm..you should've specified this in the question itself. Anyway, that will be more simple. The form values will be available in `formName.value` object. Take a look at this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-x6pelx?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: I put also form control name still I am unable to get the data.

Comment: It should have worked if everything is good. Looks like something else wrong in your code? Can you create a stackblitz with minimal code to reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please use this following input field It will update to the **opt** object when you enter the values inside the input box.

```
<div class="input-field">
 <label class="input-label">
 <input [(ngModel)]="opt.entityname" class="form-input" mdbInput placeholder="Enter the 
 input">
 </label>
</div>
```

Comment: I am using reactive form so can not put the `[(ngModel)]` inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please check this following one.

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label>First Name</label>
     <input type="text" formControlName="firstName" class="formcontrol"/>
</div>
```

**tile.ts**

```
registerForm: FormGroup;
this.registerForm = this.fb.group({
 firstName: ['', Validators.required],
)};
```

Please use following page
[Reactive form angular](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/05/10/angular-6-reactive-forms-validation-example)